# Implement Tyrant Sort

Tags: code-golf, array, sorting

### TL;DR

- Record (left-right)/length for each pair of consecutive elements. If they're 0 or negative, don't record it.
- Once this is done, take these actions. Don't update quotients:

  - Increment right and decrement left for (0, .3)
  - Remove from the array at >=.3
  - Print both elements for >.5
- Print the remaining array. Have some separator for executed and remaining.

Now, onto the challenge…

This is the sorting algorithm that has a worst-case of ***GLORIOUS LINEAR TIME***, and where any who dare oppose its ***INFINITE WISDOM*** will be promptly ***EXECUTED*** for their ***HEINOUS CRIME OF HIGH TREASON***.

The ***FEARLESS LEADER*** has tasked you with the ***HONORABLE MISSION*** of writing a program or function that takes in an array of integers and sorts it using the following sorting algorithm:

1. Iterate through your array, enlightening each element with the ***GLORIOUS*** presence of their ***FEARLESS LEADER***.
2. Have your ***SECRET POLICE*** check on every pair of 2 consecutive elements to make sure they are ***PROPERLY LOYAL TO THEIR NATION***. If they're not ordered correctly, record the difference between the numbers, divided by the length of the array. This is their dissent quotient.
3. At the end of your ***GLORIOUS TOUR***, go through the list and ***RAIN FEARLESS LEADER'S DIVINE PUNISHMENT*** on all of the ***TREASONOUS DISSENTERS*** as follows:

   - For a dissent quotient of less than .3, they merely need <s>brainwashing</s> a reminder of the ***INFINITE GLORY OF THE FEARLESS LEADER***. Decrement the left element and increment the right element. Don't change any dissent quotients.
   - For a dissent quotient of .3-.5 (inclusive), they are ***TRAITORS*** and should be sent to ***PRISON CAMPS***. Remove them from the array.
   - For a dissent quotient greater than .5, they are ***ODIOUS REBEL SCUM***. They should be ***PUBLICLY EXECUTED*** as an example for any other ***TREASONOUS HERETICS*** they might have allied with. Remove them from the array and send it to the national news source, The STDOUT Times.
4. Your array is now ***COMPLETELY AND FOREVER*** sorted. Send it to The STDOUT Times so they can sing of your ***GLORIOUS VICTORY***.

As ***MANDATORY VIEWING*** to those who are too ***FOOLISH*** to understand the ***INFINITE GLORY*** of this algorithm, it will be used to sort the following array:

```
[1,8,6,0,4,9,3,5,7,2]
```

- 1 and 8 are ordered correctly.
- 8 and 6 aren't ordered right, so the dissent quotient of .2 is recorded for both of them.
- 6 and 0 are another pair of dissenters. This dissent quotient is .6.
- 0 and 4 are ordered correctly.
- 4 and 9 are ordered correctly.
- 9 and 3 have a dissent quotient of .6.
- 3 and 5 are ordered correctly.
- 5 and 7 are ordered correctly.
- 7 and 2 have a dissent quotient of .5.

So, you take the following actions in the name of the ***FEARLESS LEADER***:

- Decrement 8 to 7, and increment 6 to 7.
- Remove 0 and the new 7, and ***EXECUTE THEM***.
- Follow with 9 and 3.
- Haul the original 7 and the 2 to the re-education camps and remove them.

This should be your press release, done in STDOUT or whatever's convenient:

```
Executions: 7, 0, 9, 3
[1, 7, 4, 5]
```

As you can see, the resulting array is ***COMPLETELY AND FOREVER SORTED***. Attempting to suggest that it isn't sorted constitutes ***HIGH TREASON***.

Now, as a ***GLORIOUS DEMONSTRATION*** of the ***UNENDING RESOURCES*** given by the ***FEARLESS LEADER***, he has provided you with his ***INFINITE WISDOM*** in generating test cases:

```python
import random

len=random.randint(2,20)
arr=list(range(len))
random.shuffle(arr)
print(arr)

dissent=[(arr[i]-arr[i+1])/len for i in range(len-1)]
dissent.append(0) # Barrier between front and back of the array.
executions=[]
for i in range(len-1):
    if dissent[i] > 0:
        if dissent[i] < 0.3:
            arr[i] -= 1
            arr[i+1] += 1
        elif dissent[i] > 0.5:
            if dissent[i-1] <= 0.5:
                executions.append(arr[i])
            executions.append(arr[i+1])

print([arr[i] for i in range(len) if dissent[i] < 0.3 and dissent[i-1] < 0.3])
print(executions)
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##jVFNb4MwDL37V1iaNCXqYNBql6nZYX8DcaDFjKg0QSHV1l/PHD5aNnZYLk6e3/Oznfbqa2t2fa/PrXUeXWFKewZoyKjxHoegjRfbp20ioXBONbrzguEPEsyTEiZmV1@qqiHBHAmtC6LhCqXuOjJeZeGd6TwawibN5TMXwMo61KgN3mpGqcxnVVy0LZlSJBIf8J2VmhweyH9SkDprPLI9HorjCW2FviZkUnGNgb7oePHamk5lOfzp8grIR1c4mXFz@IbJCK9Te0zi3T0ZzjgRRgrTNc4j4maZoWblFb/8LLgkRKzfqzVnKHWbbt7Q2IqEf7DC7mH6o2waYb0gGZoRv@eX@LgAhxYHOJ8//e4p@/4b) - hit the run button to use, otherwise you're just getting what the last person got.

In the interest of stare desecis, the ***FEARLESS LEADER*** has also provided an edge case example:

```
Input                  Output
3,2,1,4,4,1,2,3,4,5    2,2,2,4,2,3,4,5
```

(There are no executions in this example.)

Finally, you should treat the bytes in your program as [key supporters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rStL7niR7gs) and minimize them. The shortest program in bytes will win the ***ETERNAL FAVOR OF THE FEARLESS LEADER***.

### Credit where it's due

The concept for this was inspired by [Lazy Drop Sort](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/159945), and the writing style used was largely taken from [Psychotic Dictatorships](https://www.nationstates.net/region=psychotic_dictatorships)—go visit them if you enjoyed the parody aspect of this.

Additional credit goes to everyone who voted on this in [the Sandbox](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16075) early on. The +8 it attained was my motivation to rewrite it to avoid duplication.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76616/discussion-on-question-by-stephen-leppik-implement-tyrant-sort).

Comment: this needs a hell lot of renovation. More on what to do and less on stories. what do you think ?

Comment: @MuhammadSalman as with the first time this was closed, I'd really like to know what's missing from the summary.

Comment: @StephenLeppik : Nothing is missing from summary (I am pretty sure) but like I said , less stories and more to the point facts regarding what needs to be done. At least that is the reason I voted for it to be put on hold. Others may have different reasons.

Comment: +1 for the interesting idea. -1 for the unnecessary over the top writing style.  Interesting stories, while I'm not a fan of them, can be ok if they don't detract from the challenge, but I had to reread the challenge 3 times (even with the examples) to make sure I didn't miss anything.  Also in your tl;dr you are missing the point saying if left < right then dissent = 0.  Additionally, I'm pretty sure you mean left minus right, not right minus left since that would always be negative if right is less than left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>146</s> 135 bytes

```ruby
->l{e=[];i=0;l.inject{|j,k|q=(j-k)*10.0/l.size;b,c=l[i],l[i+=1];q>5&&e<<b<<c;q>0&&(l[i-1],l[i]=q<3?[b&&b-1,c&&c+1]:p);k};[l-a=[a],e-a]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVNLj9owEL7zK3wK0J1QO3Zem3j31FMPK3G1rIpEWTUQtUvZPbTAb6f2jJOwEjgeM9/D34Q/H83f26u@xU/DudPGVr3m1bDpf@279v182cPhctSrfXxYfxF8w78Om1P/r6saaPVgegtuedDCVsenNIq6um7qunUFj6KV@ykW2GH1sZbPpomiJhbQRlH7IOzj27o6XCszxDttdha6eGevN7NYGAEFZMBBQQkSUsghscDcMcuBKWCpr9yWAyuBSQsLIyEB4QDKrYkDKcCmBBh9FK5yhnuQcIXIkbVwO2oQjlU4qdQ9Mvd1CsLvJeplyCNQ2KMLNKaIgAdIQZB0FC@IberlXtw3@4Px6c8UeknIANJJ8lWieIHKEl3gJdRs13eFGzitDKV4kMqmK6oxNO8zRTokSBEYKHwkSOnj8kQTvqQeTkEl031mvjTMIyOxFGGcskIWEQhK4g@qIshQmd8FELTEqDUxIhqnmGAgnEJkd/XCFESfU3vwqO4mK8IYSZTEwsR5MIucGaJHaIlnAfSpFSUxeHrVSIIcScpbEiYnodEMhlmMoHkecm7Dt3AabGB2kgu76Xbtzx@noW@7lVxjxc6XHthvYN2FvX28n9ir@xsyrZnxZ5Y9s@XL9yV7ZMtv2@3Ldnm9/Qc)